# ElasticSearch - Get the documents where the value of a field is x and the max date of the type is lower then y date

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, nest

I have the following documents (imported from sql):

```
{
user : {
    id:1,
    efectiveDateFields : {
        items : [
                    {
                       "effectiveFrom": "2014-06-10T00:00:00",
                       "propertyValue": true
                    },
                    {
                       "effectiveFrom": "2015-03-15T00:00:00",
                       "propertyValue": false
                    }
                ]
        }
    }
},
{
user : {
    id:2,
    efectiveDateFields : {
        items : [
                    {
                       "effectiveFrom": "2014-06-13T00:00:00",
                       "propertyValue": false
                    },
                    {
                       "effectiveFrom": "2015-03-16T00:00:00",
                       "propertyValue": true
                    }
                ]
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to get a list where MAX(user.efectiveDateFields.items.effectiveFrom) <= today's date and the propertyValue : false. How can I do this with Elastic?

This is what I have so far:

```
{
"bool": {
    "must": [
        {
            "range": {
                "user.items.effectiveFrom": {
                "gte": "2013-08-28"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "term": {
                "user.items.propertyValue": false
            }
        }
    ]
   }
}
```

But its brings all the documents, because I'm not checking for the max date. Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**

The business question:

So for the business question, let divide by parts: I have a list of employees of a company. Each employee has the normal values (not dated) like, Id, Name, Birth date. 
Now, for each employee, I've got the data relative to company, that is dated. For this case, lets have a bool field that says if the employee is Director or not, and this can change over time, like a promotion. So an example data would be

```
Id: 1,
Name : Alberto Soares,
BirthDate : 1990-01-01,
isDirector {
   items:
   [
       {
             effectiveDate : 2010-05-16,
             propertyValue : false // I'm a simple employee
       },
       {
            effectiveDate : 2011-09-22,
            propertyValue : true // Because I've worked very hard, I'm now a director
       }
   ]
}
```

So now I've this data (some more records) and I want to know, at any given date, who were the directors of the company, lets say 2010-12-20. In sql I do it like the OP, but I'm complety lost on how to do it Elastic.

On my mappings (I'm using nest) I've already nested the Items (effectiveDate with propertyValue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow this is an interesting problem. 
What I have suggested below in short is pure "brain-fcuk".
The below unreadable query makes extensive use of [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) and min score.

**The query is structured to achieve the following for a given *Date*:**

**1)**  ***must-clause*** find all documents that have  at least one item document with `effective-date <= query_date` and `propertyValue:true`.

**2)**  Give the ***must query*** a score equal to  a value that denotes the min distance of nested document from the *query-date* with `property:true`. Makes use of [linear_decay](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay)

**3)**  In ***should-clause***  find all documents that have  that `effective-date <= query_date` and `propertyValue:false`.

**4)**  Same as ***2)*** give this query a score equal to min distance of nested document from the query date with `property:false`

**5)** Subtract 2) and 4) and if the result is negative it denotes the *max(effective_date) <= asked_date*  has *propertyValue:false* use [`min-score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html) to filter the documents with negative score.

## 1) Mapping Item as type Nested

```
put user/user/_mappings
    {
       "properties": {
          "id": {
             "type": "integer"
          },
          "efectiveDateFields": {
             "type": "object",
             "properties": {
                "items": {
                   "type": "nested"
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

## 2) Example Doucments for query

- *User-1 - was a director till 22-10-2015*
- *User-2 - effective director since 22-10-2015*
- *User-3 - effective director since 15-10-2015*
- *User-4 - Great Engineer not a director*

  ```
   put user/user/1
  {
          "id": 1,
          "isDirector" : {
            "items" : [
                      {
                         "effectiveFrom": "2014-06-10T00:00:00",
                         "propertyValue": false
                      },
                      {
                         "effectiveFrom": "2015-03-15T00:00:00",
                         "propertyValue": true
                      },
                       {
                         "effectiveFrom": "2015-10-22T00:00:00",
                         "propertyValue": false
                      }
                  ]
          }
  }
  put user/user/2
  {
      "id":2,
      "isDirector" : {
          "items" : [
                      {
                         "effectiveFrom": "2014-06-13T00:00:00",
                         "propertyValue": false
                      },
                      {
                         "effectiveFrom": "2015-10-22T00:00:00",
                         "propertyValue": true
                      }
                  ]
          }
      }

  put user/user/3
  {
          "id": 3,
          "isDirector" : {
            "items" : [

                      {
                         "effectiveFrom": "2015-03-15T00:00:00",
                         "propertyValue": true
                      }
                  ]
          }
  }


  put user/user/4
  {
     "id": 4,
     "isDirector": {
        "items": [
           {
              "effectiveFrom": "2011-10-23T00:00:00",
              "propertyValue": false
           }
        ]
     }
  }
  ```

## 3) Example Query (query for date 2015-10-23) :Should return 2 hits : 2,3,

```
    post user/user/_search
    {
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "disable_coord": true,
         "must": [
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "isDirector.items",
                  "query": {
                     "function_score": {
                        "functions": [
                           {
                              "linear": {
                                 "isDirector.items.effectiveFrom": {
                                    "origin": "2015-10-23",
                                    "scale": "36500d"
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        ],
                        "score_mode": "multiply",
                        "boost_mode": "replace",
                        "query": {
                           "bool": {
                              "must": [
                                 {
                                    "range": {
                                       "isDirector.items.effectiveFrom": {
                                          "lte": "2015-10-23"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "term": {
                                       "isDirector.items.propertyValue": true
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "score_mode": "max"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {
               "function_score": {
                  "functions": [
                     {
                        "weight": -1
                     }
                  ],
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {
                              "nested": {
                                 "path": "isDirector.items",
                                 "query": {
                                    "function_score": {
                                       "functions": [
                                          {
                                             "linear": {
                                                "isDirector.items.effectiveFrom": {
                                                   "origin": "2015-10-23",
                                                   "scale": "36500d"
                                                }
                                             }
                                          }
                                       ],
                                       "score_mode": "multiply",
                                       "boost_mode": "replace",
                                       "query": {
                                          "bool": {
                                             "must": [
                                                {
                                                   "range": {
                                                      "isDirector.items.effectiveFrom": {
                                                         "lte": "2015-10-23"
                                                      }
                                                   }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                   "term": {
                                                      "isDirector.items.propertyValue": false
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             ]
                                          }
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "score_mode": "max"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "min_score": 0
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try your solution of nesting, but can you explain the first part with the must_clause? Isn't that kind of redundant?

Comment: sorry did not quite got the comment , which part of the `must clause`  are you refering to the one in the filtered query ? I  just copied the initial query in OP in  the must clause  of the filtered query since i wasn't sure if that was an added constraint

Comment: I meant must_not clause, sorry.
Well, I'm trying your solution for hours, but I can't the results that are expected...

Comment: Can you explain the filter?

Comment: the `must_not` clause would work only in the case you have the constraint  `MAX(user.efectiveDateFields.items.effectiveFrom) > today` no property value constraint.

Comment: for the documents provided in the answer can you explain what exactly is the result your looking for and what your implementation returns ?

Comment: Keety, I've just updated the question with the business logic that I'm trying to get.

Comment: @Berto have updated the answer you can find an example in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/keety/6f9e843df2eadfcfb354)

Comment: wow! I just had a wtf moment reading your post! I'm going to try it, thanks for the, help, will be back if more (hopefully good) news.