# Elasticsearch - How to find out all the documents where a field value of a nested object is greater than X with the max date

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nested

I have a few documents for a company model.  Each company has some financial reports.  They are designed as **nested** object of Elasticsearch.  For example:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "financials": [
      {
        "periodEndDate": "2022-06-30",
        "cash": 10000,
        "inventory": 24000
      },
      {
        "periodEndDate": "2022-12-31",
        "cash": 12000,
        "inventory": 19000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "financials": [
      {
        "periodEndDate": "2022-12-31",
        "cash": 200000,
        "inventory": 1590000
      },
      {
        "periodEndDate": "2023-03-31",
        "cash": 210000,
        "inventory": 1430000
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to find out all the companies that have **cash > 200000** in the **most recent period end date** report.  The desired result is company 2 because the most recent report of it is the one with periodEndDate *2023-03-31*, and the cash of the report is *210000*.

How to write the query?

In addition, what is the query if I want to filter the reports with **second to the most recent date**?

I found this post:
[ElasticSearch - Get the documents where the value of a field is x and the max date of the type is lower then y date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264651/elasticsearch-get-the-documents-where-the-value-of-a-field-is-x-and-the-max-da)
But it requires "negative" filters, which does not work for me because the financial report nested object has too many fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of companies is small enough that you don't need to page through them, you can do it using combination of `top_hits` and `bucket_selector` aggregations. Basically, the `top_hits` will find the latest report and `bucket_selector` will remove all companies that don't have enough cash.

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "financials": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "periodEndDate": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "cash": {
            "type":"long"
          },
          "inventory": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"id":1,"financials":[{"periodEndDate":"2022-06-30","cash":10000,"inventory":24000},{"periodEndDate":"2022-12-31","cash":12000,"inventory":19000}]}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"id":2,"financials":[{"periodEndDate":"2022-12-31","cash":200000,"inventory":1590000},{"periodEndDate":"2023-03-31","cash":210000,"inventory":1430000}]}

POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "companies": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "financials"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "last_cash": {
              "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "financials.periodEndDate": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "_source": {
                  "includes": [
                    "financials.cash",
                    "financials.periodEndDate"
                  ]
                },
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "having.top_cash": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "last_cash": "nested>last_cash[_source.cash]"
            },
            "script": "params.last_cash > 200000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This method has several limitations including bad scalability, limited number of companies it can handle, and not supporting the second oldest report. It's also not the best solution if you will also need to sort the company by relevance or page through them.

To achieve all that functionality and to build a scalable solution I would suggest adding an additional processing during indexing time and indexing the latest report and the second to the latest report as dedicated fields in your main object instead of storing them as nested and trying to find the latest and the second latest during search time. So, basically your records should look like this:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "latest_finanicals": {
            "periodEndDate": "2022-12-31",
            "cash": 12000,
            "inventory": 19000
        }
    },
    "previous_finanicals": {
            "periodEndDate": "2022-06-30",
            "cash": 10000,
            "inventory": 24000
        }
    }
    "financials": [
      {
        "periodEndDate": "2022-06-30",
        "cash": 10000,
        "inventory": 24000
      },
      {
        "periodEndDate": "2022-12-31",
        "cash": 12000,
        "inventory": 19000
      }
    ]
  }
```

With `latest_finanicals` and `previous_finanicals` having `object` type instead of `nested` type. Then all your queries will become very simple.

Comment: Thanks for your great answers!  We have millions of companies so pagination and sorting are mandatory.  The second solution is what I have tried at the beginning.  However, there are two time type of financial report: annual and quarterly.  The PM asks to find 'the latest',  'the second latest', 'the latest annual', 'the second latest annual', 'the latest quarterly' and 'the second latest quarterly'.  Those are 6 additional objects.  And we have more models like financial reports.  If there is no other way,  I will adopt it.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure how soon you get the reports in the index relative to the period end date, but I wonder - can you express these conditions as a date range instead of as the last and second to last in the sorted list? If you can I think I can offer a better solution.

Comment: In your case you can also add a marker field on the nested object indicating the status of that report instead of creating all these additional fields. Then you will just need to add a term query on the marker field as one of the conditions. The main issue here is that you want to pick one record based on relationship with other records. If you could express the same condition as something that doesn't involve relationship between records it would have been much easier. For example, any report between now and a quarter ago instead of the last report would have simplified that.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot express the date condition as range.  For example, there are two companies A and B.  The latest report of A is on 2015-12-31.  The latest one for B is on 2023-06-30.  Although the date of the report from A looks ancient,  It is the very  latest and matches the condition.